# Will it generate 100 distinct instance variables in this condition(JS vs C++)?

Tags: javascript, c++, scope

As I remember:

`C++:`

```
for(int i= 0; i< 100;i++)
{
   int number= 3; 
}
```

We will have 100 distinct instance variables with the same name(but occupying 100 times memory as only one variable.), but variables in C++ is block scope, so the 100 variables will be recycled as the loop is finished. 

In contrast to Javascript:

`JS:`

```
for(var i=0; i < 100 ;i++)
{
    var number= 3;
}
```

1. Will it generate 100 distinct variables? Or we just have one var called number with the value `3`.

   I mean how much memory do those variables actually spend?
2. And if the for loop is not wrapped by a `function(){}`, what's the mechanism to recycle the memories which gives the variable(s)?
3. And ok, that's for primitive type variable. What if the variables are objects, will it be different?

Comment: Just to clarify, since the statements below concern JS rather, the initial claim about C++ is wrong. The scope of the variable "number" is exactly `{int number = 3}`, i.e. it will be created and destroyed once with each loop iteration. After destruction, its memory can be reused (and will be reused by any halfway decent compiler). So, it does not occupy 100 times as much memory as for one variable.

Answer (score 3):

Variables in JavaScript - unlike C - are function scoped, so you're reusing the same variable:

1. Only one variable is created.
2. If it's not wrapped in a function, `number` will be global, but will still only be created once.
3. The values don't matter. Variables are always function scoped.

Comment: And the C compiler should reuse the location of the number variable too.

Comment: Uh... for javascript loop: after the first execution, we have a variable `number`, but as it comes to the second execution, it didn't recycled yet~ And in the second execution, it does the same thing again. Why don't we have 100 variables?

Comment: @Eric Jablow I got it. Each time the number is declared, it will allocate a memory space and be recycled in each execution.(block scope). So no matter how many execution times are, there is always one integer variable called `number`,but we can't use `number` outside the loop anymore. Am I right?

Comment: Half-right.  The compiler is completely free to create just one memory location on the stack and use it for the variable number. Remember: local variables do not get initialized by default; this is why.  The compiler does not have to reset number to 0 each time through the loop. But the variable number is invisible outside the loop, and you cannot get the value of one iteration's number variable in another iteration. The compiler may do what it wants as long as nothing outside the compiler would notice.  In fact, you might want to look at the assembly code; the compiler might discard the loop.

Comment: @EricJablow     Do you mean the compiler will give the same memory address to the local variable each time instead allocating another address? Is that because of the variable name is the same?

Comment: @Joseph Siber      I'm sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: Exactly.  When the compiler reads the code of the method, it finds all the variables in it, together with their names, their types and their scopes. It does not count the number of times the loop will be executed; why should it? It's going to allocate space for the variables at compile time, not run time.  You aren't using `new` or `malloc`. Since no two instances of number will exist simultaneously, it only needs to allocate space for only one. Then, it optimizes.  If you put an identical loop in after this one, say with number2, it can realize that number and number2 can reuse their space.

Comment: @EricJablow     Thank u, I got it~